# Understanding and implementing IEEE 1284 with a parallel cable for a Epson Fx-890

Tags: microcontroller, atmega

I'm looking to gain a good understanding of the IEEE 1284 communication protocol and how to implement it for use with an Epson Fx-890 printer with a microcontroller such as the ATMega 644. Can someone provide detailed information, resources, or examples on how to implement this protocol to establish communication with the printer? I tried to find some info online but sadly failed to.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: https://hw-server.com//parallel-port-lpt-ieee-1284 If you want to have a look at how it is implemented in code, check out linux kernel sources.